# How to force rsync to stop if destination disk is full?

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, ntfs, rsync

I am using rsync (version 3.1.0 on a centos) to do some backup task. I develop a software that monitor my rsync processes to fit the backup configuration to my buisness logic.

My software launch some rsync processes, and parse rsync's output to send notifications.

I am facing something strange.

My destination disk is full. My software launch an rsync backup on that disk with the following command :

```
rsync -irlpt --no-perms --stats /src /media/dst/
```

/media/dst is an external USB3 hard drive mounted in fuseblck (NTFS).

/src is a folder conataining 50 G bytes of pictures, movies, and some text files.

Because this disk is full I would like rsync to exit quickly returning an error.

But, rsync process take a very long time. ( I stopped it manually after 10 hours) When I stopped it I can read a lot of trace like this one :

```
rsync: mkstemp "/media/dst/.20160518-130315-underwaterposition-VI_GAPS.pos.DIksdT" failed: No space left on device (28)
```

For me this message is normal because there is no space left on device.

So my questions are :

**Why does rsync doesn't stop as soon as it detect that there is no space left on destination device ?**

**Is there a way to force this behavior ?**

Comment: What version of rsync?

Comment: Version 3.1.0 (I eddited my post)

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I'm surprised there is no fix yet. I've posted a bugreport [here](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/71).